# Can't load dictionary using knockout mapping plugin

Tags: dictionary, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I found the solution how to use the observable array as dictionary on http://jsfiddle.net/karlhorky/D4D3f/

```
ko.observableArray.fn.indexBy = function (keyName) {
    var index = ko.computed(function () {
        var list = this() || [];
        var keys = {}; 
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(list, function (v) {
            if (keyName) {          
                keys[v[keyName]] = v;   
            } else {
                keys[v] = v;
            }
        });
        return keys;
    }, this);

    this.findByKey = function(key) {
        return index()[key];  
    };

    return this;
};
```

I'd like to load data to dictionary using mapping plugin

```
this.Load = function () {
    //this.items.
    var mapping = {
        'copy': ["Qid"]
    };
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this.items);
    count = 0;
};
```

but can't search by key data loaded using mapping  plugin

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RqSDv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping plugin turns regular properties into observable properties.

So in your `indexBy` you need to handle the case when your `keyName` refers to a `ko.observable`.

When you get the key property value with `v[keyName]` you need to use `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` (or `ko.unwrap` if you using a newer version of KO) to make sure to correctly unwrap your observable property:

```
ko.observableArray.fn.indexBy = function (keyName) {
    var index = ko.computed(function () {
        var list = this() || [];
        var keys = {};
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(list, function (v) {
            if (keyName) {
                keys[ko.utils.unwrapObservable(v[keyName])] = v;
            } else {
                keys[v] = v;
            }
        });
        return keys;
    }, this);

    this.findByKey = function (key) {
        return index()[key];
    };

    return this;
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VuEu3/).